# asp.net mvc Ajax.ActionLink problem

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I am doing something wrong and I can not figure out where...

I have this in my view - CreateForm.aspx

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#"  Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage" %>

      <%= this.Ajax.ActionLink("Create New", "CreateForm", new { nr=ViewData["Nr"]??0 }, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "panel" + (String.IsNullOrEmpty((string)ViewData["Nr"]) ? "0" : "1") }, new { id = "panel" + (String.IsNullOrEmpty((string)ViewData["Nr"]) ? "0" : "1") + "Form" })%>

    <div id="panel<%=String.IsNullOrEmpty((string)ViewData["Nr"])?"0":"1"%>"></div>
```

I have this in my controller -

```
        public ActionResult CreateForm(int nr)
        {
            ViewData["Nr"] = (nr++).ToString();
            return PartialView();
        }
```

when I click on the Link I expect that the response to be loaded in my panel# (panel0,panel1...) but I am redirected to an empty page with only the returned content

this is the generated html

```
<a href="/Member.aspx/CreateForm?nr=0" id="panel0Form" onclick="Sys.Mvc.AsyncHyperlink.handleClick(this, new Sys.UI.DomEvent(event), { insertionMode: Sys.Mvc.InsertionMode.replace, updateTargetId: 'panel0' });">Create New</a>

    <div id="panel0"></div>
```

and after click the page view source looks like this

```
 <a href="/Member.aspx/CreateForm?nr=0" id="panel1Form" onclick="Sys.Mvc.AsyncHyperlink.handleClick(this, new Sys.UI.DomEvent(event), { insertionMode: Sys.Mvc.InsertionMode.replace, updateTargetId: 'panel1' });">Create New</a>

    <div id="panel1"></div>
```

I have included Ajax js

```
    <script src="/content/Microsoft/MicrosoftMvcAjax.debug.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

but I expected this to go into panel0... what am I doing wrong?

P.S.

Debuging with vs.net  in MicrosoftMvcAjax.debug.js i get an error

around line 3063...

```
 var e = Function._validateParams(arguments, [
        {name: "id", type: String},
        {name: "element", mayBeNull: true, domElement: true, optional: true}
    ]);
    if (e) throw e; <-here it trows an error
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured out my problem... it seams that the version of MicrosoftMvcAjax.js I was using was not up to date....
If you have similar problems as I had get latest version of mvccontrib...

Answer (score 0):

Did you remember to include the necessary javascript files before calling AjaxLink?

You need to reference MicrosoftAjax.js and MicrosoftMvcAjax.js for this to work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I have some experience with this kind of problem. It seems like we must use script file in a correct order to make it work. More specific, you should include MicrosoftAjax before MicrosoftMvcAjax script.
Hope it helps